# Suddenly get errors in admin when editing post type

Tags: errors, json

Suddenly I've noticed something weird on my Wordpress website. When I'm logged in, the wp-admin bar isn't visible anymore. And then I wanted to change the copy of a post and my console throws a massive amount of errors:

[image]

Also the featured image box keeps loading. It seems that the image won't load.

I haven't changed anything on the code of the website and no extra plugins installed.
I've already disabled all the plugins and changed to the default WP theme. But the errors are still there.

I don't have this problem locally.

I've did some more tests and installed the classic editor plugin. I don't see any errors in the admin right now. So it feels that the issue is caused by Gutenberg editor.

Comment: Gutenberg makes use of the WordPress REST API, which has URLs in the form `/wp-json/wp/v2/`, so I think you're right that this is Gutenberg-related. If it's only happening on your hosted site, not your local environment, I recommend contacting the hosting provider to see if they have any insight.

Comment: The strange thing is that I've created a new environment on the same hosting. Copied the database and files on it. There are no errors. I think no one can understand this.

But it definitely a Gutenberg issue, because the issues are gone after installing the classic editor plugin

Comment: When I go directly to the first URL in your screenshot, I get a 401 error., because of course I'm not signed in. [Your error, 403, may indicate that the supplied credentials are insufficient.](https://httpstatuses.com/403) Maybe try clearing your cookies and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Hmm, you've brought me to an idea. I've checked my wp-config.php file and saw that the salt keys were empty. I've generated them and put them in the wp-config.php. Everything seems to work now. But don't know why.

Comment: Well, changing the salts would force all the authentication to be re-set. Glad to hear it's working, even if I can't say why.